# NSString Value of NSArray Object

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsarray

I'm trying to figure out why this code doesn't work.  I'm trying to search if a string contains "|P".  If it does, I want to do something.

```
NSMutableArray *list = [pView getPOIList];
NSString *cellValue = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
NSArray *chunks = [cellValue componentsSeparatedByString: @"|P"];
//NSLog([[chunks count] stringValue]);
if([&chunks[1] isEqualToString:@"|P"]) {
       //Do Something
}
```

This makes my app crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSArray *chunks` is a NSArray, not a C array. You can use `[chunks objectAtIndex:1]` to find the object instead of `&chunks[1]`.

To find if an sting contains an other string, you can use `([cellValue rangeOfString:@"IP"].length == 0)`. If the length of the range is 0, then the string doesn't exist in the original string. [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:)

Comment: Thanks.  objectAtIndex was the problem.  I also needed to split the string by just |, not |P.

Comment: If you are using rangeOfString it's better to look for .location = NS_NOT_FOUND (at lest I think it's a lot clearer what you are doing)

Answer (score 2):

**1.** You don't index `NSArray`s by `x[1]`. You do it by the overly verbose `[x objectAtIndex:1]`.

**2.** `componentsSeparatedByString:` will separate the string by `|P`, so if the string is:

.

```
  FOO|PURPLE|BAR|PIE|42|P|P2
```

The separated string will become

```
  ("FOO", "URPLE|BAR", "IE|42", "", "2")
```

you *will not* find an element in the resulting array containing the string `|P`. If you want to determine whether a substring exists, use `rangeOfString:`.

```
  NSRange substrRng = [cellValue rangeOfString:@"|P"];
  if (substrRng.location != NSNotFound) {
    ....
  }
```